# PHP stream_context_create() equivalent in perl

Tags: php, perl, apple-push-notifications

I am following a tutorial https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/ to implement connectivity with apple APNS server. The tutorial provided a php code for this:

```
// Open the connection
$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$apnsPort = 2195;
$apnsCert = 'apns-dev.pem';

$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

// Send the payload
$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);

// Close Resources
socket_close($apns);
fclose($apns);
```

I want to write this in Perl. What is the best equivalent of PHP's stream_context_create(). I tried something like the below, but didnt work.

```
use IO::Socket::SSL;

my $client = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
        # where to connect
        PeerHost => "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com",
        PeerPort => "2195",

        SSL_cert_file =>'localcert.pem',

    ) or die "failed connect or ssl handshake: $!,$SSL_ERROR";
```

Comment: I've never done anything related to APNS but the first thing I'd do is to search cpan for any related modules.  [CPAN search](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=apns&mode=all)

Comment: "...but didnt work...." -  and the error message is what? Also, make sure that you have a key for your client cert (SSL_key_file) and specify the version of the module you use (IO::Socket::SSL->VERSION). For SSL related debugging set `$IO::Socket::SSL::DEBUG=4`.